# Scrapy save data to mongoDB TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I am new into Python/Scrapy and facing TypeError issue. I want to store the crawler parse data to MongoDB as an object. Here is my code.

```
alertentry = {'website': host, '_id': doc['_id'], 'event': 'website_up', 'alert_id': '',
                       'main_website_id': doc['main_website_id']}
Alerts.add(alertentry, 'Website Up:' + doc[0]['website_url'], 2)
```

From above code I am getting " **alertentry = {'website': host, '_id': doc['_id'], 'event': 'website_up', 'alert_id': '',
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**"

If change alertentry to list as below, I am getting same error.

```
alertentry = [host, doc['_id'], 'website_up', '', doc['main_website_id']]
Alerts.add(alertentry, 'Website Up:' + doc[0]['website_url'], 2)
```

I also tried with:

```
alertentry = [self.host, self.doc['_id'], 'website_up', '', self.doc['main_website_id']]
```

But no luck.
Here Alerts.add() function inserts the data into MongoDB.
I am using Scrapy 1.5 with Python 3.5.
Can somebody help me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show me the content of 'doc'?

Comment: > db.websites.find().pretty()
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ac5b06d184a595812ecd48f"),
 "website" : "http://quotes.toscrape.com",
 "status" : "up",
 "threshold_images" : 0,
 "signatures" : {
  "master_signature" : {
   "links" : [ ]
  }
 },
 "main_website_id" : 9,
 "removemeta" : 0,
 "realtime_log" : "no",
 "lastscan_time" : "",
 "server_id" : 1,
 "threshold_links" : 0,
 "deep_active" : "yes",
 "removescript" : 0,
 "removehead" : 0,
 "html_exclude_regex" : "",
 "removecss" : 0,
 "max_depth" : "",
 "last_access_time" : "2018-04-05 13:15:11",
 "links" : ""
}

Comment: Currently this is the content but I more fields will be created while inserting data.

Comment: em....I think that you can print the result of doc['_id'] before the code you  show.

Comment: Same error when I print doc["_id"]. "    print(doc["_id"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

Answer (score 0):

you get this error because the type of 'doc' is an array, not dictionary. so you should get the doc['_id'] in this form

```
doc[0]['_id']
```

or you can loop on the doc.

Comment: This is actually running on loop inside "def parse(self, response): " function and this code calls parse function: yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse,
                                                 meta={'realtime_log': realtime_log, 'web_id': web_id, 'host': host,
                                                       'doc': deep_doc, 'exclude_urls': exclude_urls,
                                                       'deep_link': link})

Comment: can you print the result of doc[0]?

Comment: there is no data when print(doc[0) even print(doc)

Comment: Hi, The issue is in my query where I am getting the data from DB: "self.db.website_deepsignature.find({"$and": [{"link_level": 1}, {"website_id": web_id}]})". I changed the query to "cursor = self.db.website_deepsignature.find(
            {"$and": [{"link_level": {"$eq": 1}}, {"website_id": {"$eq": web_id}}]})" but still not fetching data. When I run updated 2nd query to Mongo console I get the data. I am confused what is wrong.

Comment: My query was worng. I changed to "self.db.website_deepsignature.find({"$and": [{"link_level": 1}, {"website_id": ObjectId("web_id")}]}) and working now.

Comment: @bhattraideb ok , congratulations